# How to change the depth of an image using imagemagick?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, file-conversion

I have tried adding the option **-depth 12** to the string

```
convert transparentPNG.png -resize 500x400 -background white -flatten -depth 12 png_small.jpg
```

The input file is a transparent png to which I'm adding a background and then changing the depth. But the depth remains the same as 8bits. I verified the same using the -verbose.

I'm not sure what could I be doing wrong here. I'm referring to the site [link](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=5947)

The transparent input png file used for my test can be found [here](https://pngtree.com/freepng/watercolor-ink-flower_151732.html)

Let me know if you have any questions on the tests i did. Hoping to get some tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A JPG can only be 8-bit, so your internal 12-bit image is converted back to 8-bit when you save the result.

Comment: Adobe photoshop has options to view an image under 8/16/32 bit. Is it something different.

Comment: So does Gimp. But the JPG file format is 8-bit, and that's all PS or Gimp can see. The fact that the image has been 12-bit during IM processing is irrelevant.